# how to make rest api call with afnetworking iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Firstly I tried the same web service with advanced rest client. it works fine. but i am having difficulty writing the equivalent in afnetworking.

here is the Webservice.

```
http://devmybartersite.pantheon.io/myrestapi/barter_user/create?str=     {"email":"sahildgfdffdfduuy@gmail.com","pass":"hello"}
```

i am able to get the response in advanced rest client in chrome. Additionally need to set a X-CSRF-Token in the header.

Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"You entered %@",self.username.text);

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

//header fields
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"vZu-YUFWLzIdFIn7VDoA6hV9IhrYe-BimkC1ncRdojU" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRF-Token"];
  [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



NSDictionary *params = @ {@"user":@"kjhkhkjhmnbbnjhio@gmail.com", @"pwd":@"hello" };


[manager POST:@"http://dev-my-barter-site.pantheon.io/myrestapi/barter_user/create" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];


 }
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: basically on button press i need to call this webservice. it is based on drupal server

Comment: **str** is the key  is the parameter or a key

Comment: thats what i dont know what to put in the parameter. str or user

Comment: can you show which type of the parameter need to pass, but your coding is correct

Answer (score 0):

Default `requestSerializer` will transform your parameters to the following format `user=kjhkhkjhmnbbnjhio@gmail.com&pwd=hello`. In order to get JSON formatted request body, use `AFJSONRequestSerializer`:

`manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"..."];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"..."];`

than you send request:

`[manager POST:....]`

Comment: so as you can see my query starts after ? in the url. still not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: Thank you so much but i am still not able to complete the request. so i set the header field as you mentioned above for x-crf token and content type. But the part that i am not sure of is the query parameter. my query parameter is ?str= {"email":"sahildgfdffdfduuy@gmail.com","pass":"hello"}. So as you can see i have a str= and then further values in json format. Now how do i send this post request.